add a linebreak in lengthy expressions
Is it possible to add a linebreak in a lengthy expression string?
sample expression in a calculate transform
{"calculate": "slice(['female', 'male'], indexof(['female', 'male'], datum['gender']), indexof(['female', 'male'], datum['gender'])+1)",
    "as": "testing"
    }

I want to add line breaks for better readibility. Something like this
{"calculate": "slice(['female', 'male'], 
indexof(['female', 'male'], datum['gender']), 
indexof(['female', 'male'], datum['gender'])+1)",
    "as": "testing"
    }


It is not possible unfortunately. You can use signals as variables to make the expressions shorter and easier to debug.

Sad, but then that's the way it is
